# FCM Admin SDK: how to send big image from server to the app

Tags: java, android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using firebase admin sdk at server end and there is no option to send big image in the sdk. Please help

Here is my code in java backend:

```
Message message = Message.builder()
                .putData("message", messageObj.getMessage())
                .setToken(messageObj.getRegistrationTokens())
                .setAndroidConfig(AndroidConfig.builder()
                        .setNotification(AndroidNotification.builder()
                                .setChannelId(messageObj.getChannel())
                                .setTitle("Title")
                                .setBody("Message")
                                .setColor("#f45342")
                                .setIcon("push_icon")
                                .build())
                        .build())
                .build();
```